# Rewiring a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a function named `fna()` that does a simple thing such as:

```
var fna = function(ar) {
    console.log("argument: ", ar);
    return "return value is argument too: " + ar;
}
```

`fna()` is coded by some other developer and I can't access to it. He didn't bother casting any events and when it is called, I have to be aware of it. Hopefully, his method is accessible by `window.fna()`.

I want some additional code to be executed. Let's say, add this `console.log`

```
var fna = function(ar) {
     console.log("Hola, I am some additional stuff being rewired");
     console.log("argument:", ar);
     return "return value is argument too: " + ar;
}
```

And I want this to be executed even when called from `fnb()` by some other part of the code.

```
var fnb = function() {
    return fna("Bonjour, I am fnb and I call fna");
}
```

Here is a way I found, using the `utils.rewire()` method. `utils` is just some utility belt, and it could be added to your favorite framework as a plugin. Unfortunately, it only works on Firefox.

```
var utils = utils || {};
// Let's rewire a function. i.e. My.super.method()
utils.rewire = function(functionFullName, callback) {
    var rewired = window[functionFullName];
    console.log("%s() is being rewired", functionFullName)

    window[functionFullName] = function() {
        callback();
        return rewired.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Use it like this.

```
utils.rewire("fna",function(){
    console.log("Hola, I am some additional stuffs being rewired");
});
```

This seems to work such as shown in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/obuDaqOY/1/edit?html,console), but (and here is my question:) **How do I rewire** `obja.fna()`**?**

```
var obja = {
    fna = function(ar) {
        console.log("argument:", ar);
        return "return value is argument too: " + ar;
    }
};
```

I cannot make it work to rewire the `some.object.method()` method.

Extra bonus question: Is there a more cleaner way to do this? Out-of-the-box clean concise and magic library?

Comment: this sounds like it will save me a lot of debugging, I always spend half an hour to put on every function "x was called"

Answer (score 4):

Refactor `rewire` into a `rewireMethod` function which acts on any given object:

```
var utils = utils || {};
utils.rewireMethod = function (obj, functionName, prefunc) {
    var original = obj[functionName];

    obj[functionName] = function () {
        prefunc();
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

Note that `rewire` can now be written as:

```
utils.rewire = function (functionName, prefunc) {
    utils.rewireMethod(window, functionName, prefunc);
};
```

Then you just call it as:

```
utils.rewireMethod(obja, "fna", function () {
    console.log("Hola, I am some additional stuff being rewired");
});
```

Note that nothing special is required if you have a method like `window.ideeli.Search.init()`. In that case, the object is `window.ideeli.Search`, and the method name is `init`:

```
utils.rewireMethod(window.ideeli.Search, "init", function () {
    console.log("Oh yeah, nested objects.");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but this doesn't solve the problem in a long run, what if my method is `window.ideeli.Search.init()` or `window.alert` and of course `window.console.log`, how could I use the same rewire method ? doing a `for` loop based on `functionName.split('.')` looks ugly too, doesn't it ?

Comment: @user2829210: then you do `utils.rewireMethod(window.ideeli.Search, 'init', ...)`, or `utils.rewireMethod(window, 'alert', ...)`, or `utils.rewireMethod(window.console, 'log', ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to `rewire` that is the object containing the function. If it's a global function, pass in `window`.

```
var utils = utils || {};
// let's rewire a function. i.e. My.super.method()
utils.rewire = function(object, functionName, callback) {
    var rewired = object[functionName];
    console.log("%s() is being rewired", functionName)

    object[functionName] = function() {
            callback();
            return rewired.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

`utils.rewire(some.object, "method", function(){} );`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a closure to create a generic hook function that allows you to specify another function to be called immediately before or after the original function:

```
function hookFunction(fn, preFn, postFn) {
    function hook() {
        var retVal;
        if (preFn) {
            preFn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        retVal = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        if (postFn) {
            postFn.apply(this, arguments);
        } 
        return retVal;
    }
    return hook;
}
```

So, for any function that you want to hook, you just call hookFunction and pass it the function you want to hook and then an optional pre and post function or yours.  The pre and post function are passed the same arguments that the original function was.

So, if your original function was this:

```
var fna = function(ar) {
     console.log("argument:",ar);
     return "return value is argument too:"+ar;
}
```

And, you want something to happen every time that function is called right before it's called, you would do this:

```
fna = hookFunction(fna, function() {
    console.log("Hola, I am some additional stuff being rewired right before");
});
```

or if you wanted it to happen right after the original was called, you could do it like this:

```
fna = hookFunction(fna, null, function() {
    console.log("Hola, I am some additional stuff being rewired right after");
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DMgn6/

---

This can be used with methods on objects and arbitrary nesting levels of objects and methods.

```
var myObj = function(msg) {
    this.greeting = msg;
};

myObj.prototype = {
    test: function(a) {
        log("myObj.test: " + this.greeting);
    }
}

var x = new myObj("hello");
x.test = hookFunction(x.test, mypreFunc2, myPostFunc2);
x.test("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Claudiu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528104/rewiring-a-javascript-function/20528201#20528201), which seems to be the most appreciated way, here is a solution using a `for` loop and proxying the context... But still, I find this ugly.

```
var utils = utils || {};
// Let's rewire a function. i.e. My.super.method()
utils.rewire = function(method, callback) {
    var obj = window;
    var original = function() {};
    var tree = method.split(".");
    var fun = tree.pop();
    console.log(tree);

    // Parse through the hierarchy
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        obj = obj[tree[i]];
    }

    if(typeof(obj[fun]) === "function") {
        original = obj[fun];
    }
    var cb = callback.bind(obj);
    obj[fun] = function(ar) {
        cb();
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks strange. Consider this

```
function wrap(fn, wrapper) {
    return function() {
        var a = arguments;
        return wrapper(function() { return fn.apply(this, a) })
    }
}
```

Example:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log([a, b])
    return a + b
}

bar = wrap(foo, function(original) {
    console.log("hi")
    var ret = original()
    console.log("there")
    return ret
})

console.log(bar(11,22))
```

Result:

```
hi
[11, 22]
there
33
```

To wrap object methods, just *bind* them:

```
obj = {
    x: 111,
    foo: function(a, b) {
        console.log([a, b, this.x])
    }
}

bar = wrap(obj.foo.bind(obj), function(fn) {
    console.log("hi")
    return fn()
})
```